# RX: ComboBox empty if bind to list<string> | ViewModelViewHost could not find a valid view for the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, reactiveui

In the `ViewModel` is a

```cs
public List<string> OperationModes { get; } = Enum.GetNames(typeof(EOperationMode)).ToList();
```

which I would like to bind to a `ComboBox`.

#### reactiveUI way | not working

```cs
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, model => model.OperationModes, window => window.ComboBoxOperationMode.ItemsSource).DisposeWith(r);
```

[image]

If using `reactiveUI` to bind the `list` to the `ComboBox`, I get the following error in the `console output`.

**console output**

```sh
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to resolve view for view model type 'System.Object'.
DefaultViewLocator: Failed to resolve view for view model type 'System.Object'.
ViewModelViewHost: The ViewModelViewHost could not find a valid view for the view model of type System.String and value Passthrough.
```

#### xaml way | working

```xml
<ComboBox
    x:Name="ComboBoxOperationMode"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.OperationModes}"/>
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Or is it not possible to bind a `list<string>` via `reactiveUI`?

---

Github Issue: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2008

Comment: In terms of binding to a list. Sure you can. You just need to follow mm8 advice. Just be aware if won't update if you change a lists contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMemberPath` property of the `ComboBox` to avoid using a `ViewModelViewHost` that tries to resolve a view for the `string`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxOperationMode" DisplayMemberPath="." />
```

Comment: You can also set a itemtemplate to avoid the issue. Since if you are binding to a ItemsSource and don't set either it attempts to look for a IViewFor for the type in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Since your list is read-only you can just assign the ItemsSource directly without needing OneWayBind (either via code or via xaml like you already have it). ReactiveUI binding is powerful but it comes with a cost, so if you can get away with direct assignments, do it. And even if your list changes over time, you can still avoid ReactiveUI binding with the help of an ObservableCollection rather than a list.

Comment: So that means, use xaml binding wherever it is possible due of performance? Is that a bug that I cannot bind my list<string> via reactive?

Comment: See mm8 for a more complete answer. I wouldn't agree with colts opinion 100% there. There is a slight penalty at initialisation time in wpf land otherwise it's reasonably efficient.

Comment: Well, I wasn’t saying it’s inefficient, otherwise I wouldn’t be using it myself. So I agree it is reasonably efficient. My point was that everything comes with a cost, even if small. So if a variable or list doesn’t change over time, it will always be more efficient to do direct assignment. This becomes more important when you do binding within list items.